# why @ ( a round) is not displayed in LaTeX lstlisting

Tags: latex, pdflatex, texstudio

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report} 

\usepackage{OvidiusFMI}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color,xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,epsfig,epstopdf,url,array}
\usepackage{multicol,multirow}
\usepackage{needspace}
\include{custom-lst-style}
%these are all packages im using

\begin{document}
  \begin{lstlisting}
   npm install @material-ui/core
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

I have to add a lstlisting to my latex.

Original text : **npm install @material-ui/icons**

Latex text: **npm install material-ui/icons** (no @ symbol)

How could I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you make a [mre]? By default this works fine. Maybe you set up listings to use @ as escape character?

Comment: this is the code i wrote in TeXstudio:
\begin {lstlisting}
nmp install @material-ui/core
\end{lstlisting}

. In the output PDF, i don't see @ symbol

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre] that starts with a documentclass and ends with `\end{document}` so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: This works without problem: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
 npm install @material-ui/icons
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}` So we really must see your code to see what's going wrong there

Comment: I'm also using a custom package, perhaps it is getting me in trouble. However I managed to pass this problem by adding a screenshot of the code I need, but I'm still curious why I cannot add @

Comment: what does `custom-lst-style.tex` contain?

Comment: Oh, I've inspected it and found \lstset{escapechar=@,style=customc}. This is a predefined lst-style I'm using for my project. Thank you, now I understood. You should post an answer, so I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was solved due to **user:2777074**'s crystall ball. If you will encounter such things like I had ( not displaying a character), you should check for your listing styles.

In my case I was using `\include{custom-lst-style}` that had the next line of code:`\lstset{escapechar=@,style=customc}` and because of that I was unable to display **@** character.